# Is it possible to make pieces on a chessboard in batch files move with user inputs?

Tags: batch-file

I made the chess board, with the pieces on it. When you run the batch file, it looks like this:[image: this is what you see before you put a move]and when you try to input the move you want, it gives you this:[image: this is what you see when you try and play a move]

What I want, is when the player enters their move, it shows up on the chess board. So, if this is possible, I would like for someone to help me out. I am at a loss here.

```
  A B C D E F G H
1  RNBQKBNR
2  pppppppp
3  ........
4  ........
5  ........
6  ........
7  pppppppp
8  RNBQKBNR
   A B C D E F G H
```

to this:

```
   A B C D E F G H
1  RNBQKBNR
2  pppppppp
3  ........
4  ........
5  p.......
6  ........
7  .ppppppp
8  RNBQKBNR
   A B C D E F G H
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```bash
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Initialize the chessboard
set chessboard[1]=RNBQKBNR
set chessboard[2]=pppppppp
set chessboard[3]=........
set chessboard[4]=........
set chessboard[5]=........
set chessboard[6]=........
set chessboard[7]=pppppppp
set chessboard[8]=RNBQKBNR

:print_board
cls
echo   A B C D E F G H
for /L %%i in (1,1,8) do (
    set "row=!chessboard[%%i]!"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo %%i  !row: =!
    endlocal
)
echo   A B C D E F G H

:move_piece
echo.
set /p "start_pos=Enter the starting position of the piece (e.g., a2): "
set /p "end_pos=Enter the destination position of the piece (e.g., a5): "

rem Extract row and column numbers from the input
set /a "start_row=9-%start_pos:~1%"
set /a "start_col=%start_pos:~0,1%"
set /a "end_row=9-%end_pos:~1%"
set /a "end_col=%end_pos:~0,1%"

rem Get the piece at the starting position
set "piece=!chessboard[%start_row%]:~%start_col%,1!"

rem Move the piece to the destination
set "chessboard[%start_row%]=!chessboard[%start_row%]:~0,%start_col%!.!chessboard[%start_row%]:~%start_col%+1%!"
set "chessboard[%end_row%]=!chessboard[%end_row%]:~0,%end_col%!%piece%!chessboard[%end_row%]:~%end_col%+1%!"

goto print_board
```

I tried looking online for a solution, but all the stuff I found ended up either closing out of the file when you input a move, or messing up the chess board.

It is a pain to find help on this sort of thing, because batch is not the first thing that comes to mind when you try to make a game. I want, at least, to try to ask for help from people more experience then me, before I give up, and move this project to python for JavaScripter.

Comment: There's a character limit that I'll hit if I want to try and actually answer the question, but the short version is yes, and you'll need a 2D array that represents the board squares (right now you have a 1D array).